# this data adapter does not provide any facility to retrieve the fields

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I tried to connect with sql server data adapter in jasper reports but iam not able to retrive the fileds from database it showing like below

"this data adapter does not provide any facility to retrieve the fields"

Can any one give me a solution.

Comment: What designer are you using (iReport or Studio)?

Comment: iam using JasperStudio plugin in Eclipse Alex.

Comment: You need to provide more info, we can not reproduce this as the question is, what adapter are you using (which class library to connect sql server)

Comment: I am tring to connet with "Database JDBC Connection" using jtds library.

Comment: @M.Siva You can always add fields manually

Comment: How can i add database fields manually ?

Comment: <field name="theNameOfColumn" class="java.lang.String"/> the class needs to be the corresponding java class of your columnType